# JQuery DatePicker not showing up in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a problem regading datepicker. I am currently using MVC4. So here is the case, I have my OtherReports.cshtml (which is the main view and where my tabs are located. Codes are displayed below)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Other Reports";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterPageLayout.cshtml";
}

<div id="reportsContainer">

    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#ExtractedClaims">Extracted Claims</a></li>
            <li><a href="#RejectedClaims">Rejected Claims</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PendingClaims">Pending Claims</a></li>
            <li><a href="#IBNRClaims">IBNR Claims</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PaidClaims">Paid Claims</a></li>
            <li><a href="#UnprocessedLOA">Unprocessed LOA</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="ExtractedClaims"></div>
        <div id="RejectedClaims"></div>
        <div id="PendingClaims"></div>
        <div id="IBNRClaims"></div>
        <div id="PaidClaims"></div>
        <div id="UnprocessedLOA"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.get('/LablinkDoctorLink/ExtractedClaimsLoadLeftNavigation', function (data) {
            $('#leftNavigationBody').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>

  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#tabs").tabs();
      });
    //ExtractedClaims
      $(function () {
          $('#tabs a[href="#ExtractedClaims"]').on('click', function () {
              $(function () {
                  $.get('/LablinkDoctorLink/ExtractedClaimsLoadLeftNavigation', function (data) {
                      $('#leftNavigationBody').html(data);
                  });
              });
          });
      });

</script>
```

and I have my partial view which is the left Navigation of UnprocessedLOA (below code is shown)

```
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script>
          $(function () {

              $("#txtDateCreatedFrom").datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true
              });

              $("#txtDateCreatedTo").datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true
              });
          });
  </script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date Created - From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtDateCreatedFrom" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>To:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtDateCreatedTo" class="form-control" />
</div>
<br />
<div style="float: right;">
    <button type="button" id="btnUnprocessedLoaSearch" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>
</div>
```

My problem now is: Why is it that the datepicker i placed in my _UnprocessedLeftNav is not showing up? Every I time i click on my TextBox, it does shows up? Any help?

Comment: Hi, Could you put all your script references in the layout. or put it in the bundle.cs file

Comment: you dont need to include css and js files again in partial view, if you are including them in main view, you must add all css files and js files to the master layout